# Store Target.Address in a variable

Tags: excel, vba

What i am trying to achieve is that a user inputs a value into column B for instance and if its below a limit (say 50) then you look at the date in column A and change the sheet tab colour of that date to red if its below 50.

However i am having issues with putting target.adress into a variable and i keep getting a type mismatch error.

This is what i have currently.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim R as integer
dim c as integer
Dim cl As Range
Dim Tb As Range
Dim RG As Range

Set RG = Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B50"))
Set Tb = Target.Address
Set r = Tb.row
Set c = Tb.column - 1
Set cl = cells(R,C).value 
Set cl = Replace(cl, "/", ".")

    If RG Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
    ElseIf Target.Value < 50 Then
       cl.Tab.Color = vbRed

        End If
End Sub
```

The set *tb = target.address* doesnt seem to work no matter what i do.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Set Tb = Target.Address` should be `Set Tb = Target`.

Comment: `Target.Address` returns a String, not a Range. Change your Dim and do not use Set.

Comment: Since you are using `Set r = Tb.row` i.e tb as range, I recommend keeping it as `Range` and not `String`. You can (whenever you want) get the address using `Tb.address`

Comment: Either that or you can always just use `Target.Row` to get the row. Seems like a bit of a waste to make an exact copy of `Target`.

Comment: You will get the next error on `Set cl = cells(R,C).value ` ;) I am sure that you have now understood how to fix it?

Comment: And while we have you here, you should probably define `r` as a `Long` instead of an `Integer` just in case it ever needs to be larger than 32,767 - It's good practice to always use a `Long` for row variables.

Answer (score 1):

This may helps you:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim tb
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim Col As Long

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then

        tb = Target.Address
        Row = Target.Row
        Col = Target.Column

    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly declared the `tb` object as `Range` since you are using it as a range later in the code. The problem is that both `Target` and `tb` are range and you are trying to store a `String` to a range.

Change

```
Set Tb = Target.Address
```

to

```
Set Tb = Target
```

Few other things.

1. Since you are working with rows, better to use `Long` instead of `Integer` to avoid any possible overflow error. Of course you are working with a very small range here so that situation may not arise.
2. You will get the next error on `Set cl = cells(R,C).value` ;) I am sure that you have now understood how to fix it?

Btw your code can be reduced to this (**Untested**). You may want to also read about error handling [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Long, c As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B50")) Is Nothing Then
            r = Target.Row
            c = Target.Column - 1
            Cells(r, c).Value = Replace(Cells(r, c).Value, "/", ".")

            If Target.Value < 50 Then ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = vbRed
        End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set r` and `Set c` ? They are not objects

Comment: @braX: This is what happens when you post without testing :( which i rarely do...